# Definite integration of vectors

Tags: matlab, indexing, numerical-methods, integral

In matlab how to do definite integration of a vector `f(i)` in terms of `x(i)` where `x(i)` varies from `zero` to `infinity` i.e. something of the sort `f(i)dx(i)`?

Answer (score 1):

whether you set up the integration scheme yourself with something like:

- calculate a `x` and `f(x)` vector
- calculate `dx` by using the `diff` function
- multiply it with f(x) and take the sum of all Elements

Or you use Matlab's build-in functions `q = integral(fun,xmin,xmax,Name,Value)`.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

A little addition to [M_Tornack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41758473/4960953):

1) if you know function `f(x)` you can calculate it in some of this ways:

calculate symbolically

```
syms x f
f=1./x; % for example
integral(f,x,-inf,0);
```

or another way:
using [quadgk](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quadgk.html;jsessionid=b132e13e8bad76a957ff9ef72d2b) function - Numerically evaluate integral, adaptive Gauss-Kronrod quadrature

2) another way: using small values instead of `Inf` and `zero` and then use `trapz` built-in function.
Or you can use first algorithm from [M_Tornack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41758473/4960953) using some tolerance - not using `Inf` values of `x` but increase it while increasing of result integral less then tolerance.

Hope it helps!